# Loop through hex variable in C

Tags: c++, c, hex

I have the following code in a project that `write`'s the ascii representation of `packet` to a unix tty:

```
int written = 0; 
int start_of_data = 3; 
//write data to fifo 
while (length) { 
        if ((written = write(fifo_fd, &packet[start_of_data], length)) == -1) 
{ 
                printf("Error writing to FIFO\n"); 
        } else { 
                length -= written; 
        } 
}
```

I just want to take the data that would have been written to the socket and put it in a variable. to debug, I have just been trying to `printf` the first letter/digit. I have tried numerous ways to get it to print out, but I keep getting hex forms (I think).

The expected output is: 13176
and the hex value is: 31 33 31 37 36 0D 0A (if that is even hex)

Obviously my C skills are not the sharpest tools in the shed. Any help would be appreciated.

**update:** I am using `hexdump()` to get the output

Comment: If you are getting hex numbers `printf`ed out, then you really should show us your `printf` statements.  I'd suspect you've got a `%x` format code, when it should be `%c` or `%d`.

Comment: First, if write ever doesn't write the entire length then it will always start over from the same place when it tries to write the rest because `start_of_data` doesn't change (`start_of_data+=written;`).  Second, what is the type of `packet` and where does it get set?

Comment: If you're using something called `hexdump()` to get the output, it shouldn't be surprising when the output is in, um, hex.  Even if you have no clue as to what hex is (which is obvious from the question), you should realize that it's likely to dump information in hex, and not being surprised at the output.  You said you've been trying to `printf` some data unsuccessfully; if so, you could show us `printf` statements and we could help there.

Comment: I'm not a complete idiot, mind you. Your 20K rep shouldn't entitle you to "smartass" privileges. I was using `printf("%20x", &packet[3]);`, and fixed it by using the `%s` formatting option. Which, interestingly was neither `%c` or `%d`.

Comment: I don't rely on my rep for "smartass" privileges, I claim them independently.  Had you actually shown us what you were using for `printf`, as requested, earlier, somebody could have answered you quickly with the right answer.  When you don't know what you're doing, include more information, since you won't know what's relevant.  Peter's answer on format specifiers was based on intelligent speculation (slightly more intelligent than mine, as I was thinking of a drop-in replacement for `%x`), not anything you specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) of characters: 31 is '1', 33 is '3' etc. 0D and 0A are the terminating new line characters, also known as '\r' and '\n', respectively. So if you convert the values to characters, you can print them out directly, e.g. with `printf` using the `%c` or `%s` format codes. As you can check from the table linked, the values you posted do represent "13176" :-)